# Mapping multiple columns in R including a single column containing comma-separated values

Tags: r

This problem involves mapping multiple columns while adhering to certain constraints. It looks very difficult to me, since I'm not sure how to unnest the `region` column in `cat` and allow matching the `df` data.

Problem: I want to match three columns from the data frame `df` to four columns on the data frame `cat`.

The result should adhere to the following conditions:

1. `loss_date` in `df`should be >= `StartDate` and <= `EndDate` in `cat`.
2. `line_of_business` in `df` should match `line_of_business` in `cat`.
3. `region` in `df` should match `region` in `cat` (note: `region` in `cat` needs to be unnested).

If all three conditions are met, an output column should return logical `TRUE`, otherwise it should return logical `FALSE`.

DATA:

```
df
loss_date   line_of_business            region
10/8/2018   Property                      NB
1/31/2019   Commercial Property Line      BC
8/1/2018    Auto                          AB
3/20/2019   Personal Property             ON
11/10/2018  Homeowners Line             Alberta

cat
Start Date  End Date    line_of_business            region
11/1/2018   11/30/2018  Homeowners Line            Alberta
10/1/2018   10/21/2018  Property                 AB,BC,MB,ATL,ON,PQ
4/9/2018    4/10/2018   Commercial Property         ATL
4/26/2018   5/22/2018   Auto                   BC, AB, PQ, ON, ATL
```

OUTPUT:

```
loss_date   line_of_business            region      output
10/8/2018   Property                    MB          TRUE
1/31/2019   Commercial Property Line    BC          FALSE
8/1/2018    Auto                        AB          FALSE
3/20/2019   Personal Property           ON          FALSE
11/10/2018  Homeowners Line          Alberta         TRUE
```

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `separate_rows` from `tidyr`. We bring the comma-separated values from `region` column into different rows and do a join with `df`. Convert the date using `as.Date` and check if `loss_date` is between `StartDate` and `EndDate` and if the `region` matches.

```
library(dplyr)

cat %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(region, sep = ",") %>%
  right_join(df, by = "line_of_business") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("ate")), as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y") %>%
  group_by(line_of_business) %>%
  summarise(temp = any(region.x %in% region.y & loss_date >= StartDate & 
                       loss_date <= EndDate)) %>%
  left_join(df)

#  line_of_business         temp  loss_date  region 
#  <chr>                    <lgl> <chr>      <chr>  
#1 Auto                     FALSE 8/1/2018   AB     
#2 Commercial_Property_Line FALSE 1/31/2019  BC     
#3 Homeowners_Line          TRUE  11/10/2018 Alberta
#4 Personal_Property        FALSE 3/20/2019  ON     
#5 Property                 TRUE  10/8/2018  MB
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(loss_date = c("10/8/2018", "1/31/2019", "8/1/2018", 
"3/20/2019", "11/10/2018"), line_of_business = c("Property", 
"Commercial_Property_Line", "Auto", "Personal_Property", "Homeowners_Line"
), region = c("MB", "BC", "AB", "ON", "Alberta")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame") 

cat <- structure(list(StartDate = c("11/1/2018", "10/1/2018", "4/9/2018", 
"4/26/2018"), EndDate = c("11/30/2018", "10/21/2018", "4/10/2018", 
"5/22/2018"), line_of_business = c("Homeowners_Line", "Property", 
"Commercial_Property", "Auto"), region = c("Alberta", "AB,BC,MB,ATL,ON,PQ", 
"ATL", "BC,AB,PQ,ON,ATL")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for `base R`:

```
df$output <- apply(df, 1, function(v) 
        with(cat, any(difftime(as.Date(v[1],format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date(StartDate,format="%m/%d/%Y"))>=0 & 
                    difftime(as.Date(v[1],format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date(EndDate,format="%m/%d/%Y"))<=0 &
                    v[2] == line_of_business &
                    grepl(v[3],region))))
```

yielding:

```
> df
   loss_date         line_of_business  region output
1  10/8/2018                 Property      MB   TRUE
2  1/31/2019 Commercial_Property_Line      BC  FALSE
3   8/1/2018                     Auto      AB  FALSE
4  3/20/2019        Personal_Property      ON  FALSE
5 11/10/2018          Homeowners_Line Alberta   TRUE
```